# Valores en HashMap

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

¿Existe alguna forma en la que un `HashMap` agregue un un objeto y le sume/agregue sus datos de forma directa al value?. Es decir si la llave ya existe o que lo agregue sin necesidad de hacer una verificación de esta (Hashmap.get(key), etc). Gracias

EJM: Mi HashMap sería:

```
public static HashMap<Color,Integer> finalPopulation = new HashMap<Color,Integer>();
```

Y un ejemplo de lo deseado es:

```
Hashmap existente = {rojo = 4, verde = 5}
Color añadir = rojo
Color añadir = azul
```

Resultado: `Hashmap existente = {rojo = 5, verde = 5, azul = 1}`

Comment: Aquí hay varias formas de solucionarlo fácilmente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81346/most-efficient-way-to-increment-a-map-value-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Claro, en tu caso sería algo así:

```
existente.merge(color, 1, (prev, actual) -> prev + actual);
```

El método merge acepta 3 parámetros:

1. La clave que agregas al map, en tu caso el color.
2. El valor que asociado a la clave que estás agregando. Este valor se usará diréctamente si la clave no existe aún en el mapa, o bien se pasa a la función del 3er parámetro. En tu caso es 1 porque cada color representa una ocurrencia de ese color.
3. Una función que calcula el nuevo valor si la clave ya existe. Los parámetros que te pasa son el valor que ya tenía el mapa para esa clave, y el valor que le estás pasando ahora (1 en tu caso). Por lo tanto el nuevo valor será el anterior + el actual (que siempre es 1 en tu caso, por lo que también podrías hacer prev++).

Comment: Solo añadir que `Map.merge()` está disponible de Java 8 en adelante: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-